# Java Process - Too short lifetime of the process. (Less than 1s...)

Tags: java, process, lifetime

### Problem:

`this.proc.IsAlive` in function `make_test` return false... I don't know why...
Normally waits for a user command... (In the case of the console)

External Program:
`-> L10_Z1_external_test`

Target:
Process should life...

### L10_Z1__Test__Core.java

```
package BST_Test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class L10_Z1__Test__Core {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Build Proccess
        ProcessBuilder pr_1 = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "../BST.jar");
        try {
            Process proc = pr_1.start();
            L10_Z1__Test__C_Tester test_engine = new L10_Z1__Test__C_Tester(
                    proc);
            String[] cmd;
            String[] result;
            cmd = new String[] { "add", "remove" };
            result = new String[] { "Sucess (add) | ", "Sucess (remove) | ",
                    "Sucess (add) | ", "Sucess (remove) | ",
                    "Sucess (add) - Duplicate | ",
                    "Error (remove) - Not found | ",
                    "Error (Parse) - Invalid integer or Overflow | ",
                    "Error (remove) - Not found | ", "Sucess (add) | ",
                    "Sucess (remove) | ", "Sucess (add) | ",
                    "Sucess (remove) | ", "Sucess (add) | ",
                    "Sucess (remove) | ", "Sucess (add) | ",
                    "Sucess (remove) | ", "Sucess (add) | ",
                    "Sucess (remove) | ", "Sucess (add) | ",
                    "Sucess (remove) | ",
                    "Error (Parse) - Invalid integer or Overflow | ",
                    "Error (remove) - Not found | " };
            test_engine.make_test("ADD & search",
                    "This test check - how work add & remove", cmd, result,
                    new String[] { "-3", "4", "-3", "aa", "12", "5", "12", "7",
                            "-12", "-50", "-999999999" });

            // Stop test;
            test_engine.stop();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error - Problem with init | java -jar "
                    + "../BST.jar");
        }
    }
}
```

### L10_Z1__Test__C_Tester.java

```
package BST_Test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class L10_Z1__Test__C_Tester{

    private boolean is_run; /** Information about Victim of Test ;) */
    private Process pr_proc; /** Victim process */

    private BufferedReader ProcessOut;
    private BufferedWriter ProcessIn;

    /**
     * Default construtor with invoke test subject.
     * @prog_name {String} name of test_subject (Program name: eg. closure.java)
     */
    L10_Z1__Test__C_Tester (Process in){
        this.is_run = false;
        this.pr_proc = in;
        if(this.pr_proc.isAlive()){
            this.ProcessOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.pr_proc.getInputStream()));
            this.ProcessIn = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.pr_proc.getOutputStream()));
            this.is_run = true;
        }
    }


    /**
     * This method create test and invoke. While test is runing -> Program send cmd into process, get result and validate it. (For Multi arguments
     * @param name {String} Name of Test
     * @param desc {String} Description of Test
     * @param cmd {String[]} The commands that are sent into program.
     * @param c_res {String[]} The correct output.
     * @param data  {String[]} The test data.
     */
    public void make_test(String name, String desc, String[] cmd, String[] c_res, String[] data){
        if(this.is_run && this.pr_proc.isAlive()){
            System.out.println("/********************** [" + name + "] - #START **********************/");
            System.out.println("Desc: " + desc);
            int j;
            String out;
            for(int i = 1; i <= data.length; i++){
                System.out.println("\n\nLoop - " + i);
                for(j = 1; j <= cmd.length && this.pr_proc.isAlive(); j++){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("in: - " + cmd[(j - 1)] + " " + data[(i - 1)]);
                        this.ProcessIn.write(cmd[(j - 1)] + " " + data[(i - 1)]);
                        this.ProcessIn.flush();
                        out = this.ProcessOut.readLine();
                        System.out.println("out: - " + out +
                                       "----------------------------------" +
                                       "status: - " + this.check(out, c_res[(i - 1) * (j - 1)] + data[(i - 1)]));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Error - Problem with reader/writte buffer");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("/********************** [" + name + "] - #END **********************/");
        }
    }
    /**
     * This method create test and invoke. While test is runing -> Program send cmd into process, get result and validate it. (For one argument)
     * @param name {String} Name of Test
     * @param desc {String} Description of Test
     * @param cmd {String[]} The commands that are sent into program.
     * @param c_res {String[]} The correct output.
     */
    public void make_test(String name, String desc, String[] cmd, String[] c_res){
        if(this.is_run){
            System.out.println("/********************** [" + name + "] - #START **********************/");
            System.out.println("Desc: " + desc);
            int count = cmd.length;
            String out;
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                System.out.println("\n\nLoop - " + i);
                try {
                    System.out.println("in: - " + cmd[i]);
                    this.ProcessIn.write(cmd[i]);
                    out = this.ProcessOut.readLine();
                    System.out.println("out: - " + out +
                                   "----------------------------------" +
                                   "status: - " + this.check(out, c_res[i]));
                    this.ProcessIn.flush();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error - Problem with reader/writte buffer");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("/********************** [" + name + "] - #END **********************/");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function validate a output for test subject
     * @param out {String} out to compare with cp
     * @param cp {String} Correct Template
     * @return {String} status of test.
     */
    public String check(String out, String cp){
        if(out.equals(cp))
            return "OK";
        else
            return "FAIL";
    }

    /**
     * Stop operation -> Stop Process, close buffer...
     */
    public void stop(){
        if(this.is_run && this.pr_proc.isAlive() ){
            try {
                this.ProcessIn.close();
                this.ProcessOut.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error - Problem with closing I/O buffers");
            }
            this.pr_proc.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

### L10_Z1_external_test.java

```
package BST;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class L10_Z1_external_test {


    private L10_Z1__BST BST;

    /**
     * Default constructor with L_10_Z1__BST init;
     */
    L10_Z1_external_test()
    {
        this.BST = new L10_Z1__BST();
    }

    /**
     * This class nitialize, a line reader and controler.
     */
    public void init()
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = null;

        try {
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null && !s.equals("quit"))
            {
                this.switch_f(s.split(" "));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error - Unknow I/O problem.");
        }


        System.out.println("Bye");

    }

    /**
     * This method procces user request into BST - Tree functions or specyfied errors
     * @param in {String} - with request, String Format (<command> <number>)
     */
    public void switch_f(String[] in)
    {

        String text = null, error_text = "Error - Unknow command";


        if(in.length == 2)
        {

            int number = 0;
            boolean op_status = true;

            try
            {
                number = Integer.parseInt(in[1]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                op_status = false;
                System.out.println("Error (Parse) - Invalid integer or Overflow | " + in[1]);
            }

            if(op_status)
                if( in[0].equals("add"))
                {
                    text = "Add";

                    try {
                        this.BST.add(number);
                        System.out.println("Sucess (" + text + ") | " + number);
                    } catch (L10_Z1__BST_Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("Error (" + text + ") - " + ex.getMessage() + " | " + number);
                    }
                }
                else if( in[0].equals("remove"))
                {
                    text = "Remove";

                    try {
                        this.BST.remove(number);
                        System.out.println("Sucess (" + text + ") | " + number);
                    } catch (L10_Z1__BST_Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("Error (" + text + ") - " + ex.getMessage() + " | " + number);
                    }
                }
                else if( in[0].equals("search"))
                {
                    text = "Search";

                    if(this.BST.search(number))
                        System.out.println("Sucess (" + text + ") | " + number);
                    else
                        System.out.println("Error (" + text + ") - | " + number);
                }
                else
                    System.out.println(error_text);

        }
        else if(in.length == 1)
            if( in[0].equals("list"))
            {
                text = "List";

                try {   
                    this.BST.print_list(this.BST.list_in_order());
                } catch (L10_Z1__BST_Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error (" + text + ") - " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            else
                System.out.println(error_text);
        else
            System.out.println(error_text);

    }    
}
```

Comment: Post all code that you are asking your question about here, in your question on SO. Don't post links. Links go stale, and if you want people to help you don't want to send them over the internet to find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking that the process is actually started using your process monitor?  I would isolate the problem by going through a series of steps:

1. Make sure a simple command that you create by starting a ProcessBuilder Process actually spawns a process in your operating system.  If not, perhaps there is a problem related to concurrency or command syntax.
2. If you are able to start a process, start one that you can clearly see is not terminating in the process monitor and call isAlive on that process.  If you can get a True returned for that, you should look at the architecture of your testing framework to make sure everything is working as intended.